# Firing click event before ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an `ajax` call on click of anchor tag in WordPress and I have not control over this. But before this `ajax` call I want to fire click event.
This click event is firing sometime but not every time. So I am not getting consistent results. Is there any way so that I can get correct results and get this click event fire before `ajax` call. I have tried putting my code in header and in footer as well.

Here is my code that i am using for click event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#addbtn").click(function(){
    });
});
```

Any suggestion about this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to trigger an event of listen the triggered event? Confused...

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As i am in WordPress and i have no control over WordPress functions. So here in this case this ajax call is controlled by WordPress. But i want to fire click event before this ajax call. I am using above code for this purpose and this code is working and firing click event but sometime it does not fire and ajax call runs directly. So my question, how i can fire this click event before ajax call all the time to get consistent results. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this will be your friend: [link](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use befor `beforeSend`
This event, which is triggered before an Ajax request is started, allows you to modify the XMLHttpRequest object (setting additional headers, if need be.)
source: https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {       
         /*using a loader while waiting or fire an event or execute a function  */     
    },
    success: function(data) {
       //execute a function on request sucess
    },
    error: function(xhr) { // if error occured
        alert("Error occured.please try again");

    },
    complete: function() {
      //execute a function once the call completed
    }

});
```

I hope this will help you slove the issue